# Joining Array Values

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have 3 arrays, think of each as a dimension:

```
Aa = {{{1}, {1}, {1}}, {{1}, {1}, {1}}, {{1}, {1}, {1}}}
Bb = {{{2}, {2}, {2}}, {{2}, {2}, {2}}, {{2}, {2}, {2}}}
Cc = {{{3}, {3}, {3}}, {{3}, {3}, {3}}, {{3}, {3}, {3}}}
```

I want to join them so I can play with them in 3D vector plotting functions.

i.e. so it would look like

```
Jj = {{{1,2,3}, {1,2,3}, {1,2,3}}, {{1,2,3}, {1,2,3}, {1,2,3}},
      {{1,2,3}, {1,2,3}, {1,2,3}}}
```

Comment: Maybe like this? `MapThread[Sequence, {Aa, Bb, Cc}, 3]`. (Note that it would be easier to figure out what you want if you put different symbols in each spot.  It's unclear exactly how the lists are to be joined.

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted. I can see why it would be confusing.

Comment: Another possibility?  `ArrayReshape[Transpose[Flatten /@ {Aa, Bb, Cc}], {3, 3, 3}]`

Comment: `Join[Aa, Bb, Cc, 3]`?

Comment: Is my comment a valid way too? I didn't post an answer because your example can be reproduced from input in many ways. It would be nice to have less ambiguous set of elements there, like `a[1,1,1]` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@LouisB and I have propose the following solution

```
Transpose /@ ArrayReshape[Transpose@{Aa, Bb, Cc}, {3, 3, 3}]
```

or

```
ArrayReshape[Transpose[Flatten /@ {Aa, Bb, Cc}], {3, 3, 3}]
```

and as mentioned by @march

```
MapThread[Sequence, {Aa, Bb, Cc}, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

`Flatten[]` is nice enough that you don't really need to use anything else:

```
Flatten[{Aa, Bb, Cc}, {{3, 4}, {2}, {1}}]
   {{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}},
    {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}}
```

If you insist on using `Transpose[]`:

```
First[Transpose[{Aa, Bb, Cc}, {4, 3, 2, 1}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Join @@@ # & /@ Flatten[{Aa, Bb, Cc}, {{3}, {2}}] == Jj
```

> True

Comment: wow. nice. +1 ! I thought of a slight variation of your code if you wish to incorporate `Flatten[{Aa, Bb, Cc}, {{3}, {2}}] /. p : {{_Integer} ..} :> Flatten@p`